# Connection timed out when doing deployment of ear file

Tags: jakarta-ee

I getting the following error:

Deploying application in domain failed; Error loading deployment descriptors for jrules-teamserver-SUNAS82 -- Connection timed out ; requested operation cannot be completed Error loading deployment descriptors for jrules-teamserver-SUNAS82 -- Connection timed out

When deploying a ear file.
What could be the possible cause Connection timed out and how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

there is a possibility that the your deployment tool was NOT able to connect to the appserver at all. It was trying to get a network connection and that connection was not established : after TIMING OUT , it gave the error

Can you find out which appserver it is trying to connect to >?